# Angular [ngClass] condition and function combined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Is it possible to combine the conditional statement and the function together in the [ngClass]

```
 [ngClass]="tagType.tagColor ? 'tags-button' : 'tags-button tag-colorless' &&  getStyleClasses()"
```

I get an error on syntax above, is there a correct way to include the conditional statement and the function together? The function should just evaluate on its own without a condition

Comment: how about adding `tags-button tag-colorless` inside the return value of `getStyleClasses()` ?

Comment: Keep `tags-button tag-colorless` inside `getStyleClasses()`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with this syntax.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: you are evaluating `'tags-button tag-colorless'`, which is always true, so the result is always substituted by `getStyleClasses()`. Maybe you meant concatanation, so substitute `&&` with `+`

Comment: @CristianTraìna you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating `'tags-button tag-colorless'`, which is always true, so the result is always substituted by `getStyleClasses()`.

In JavaScript, the last value of an evaluation get returned, for example:

```
var x = true && 'foo';
```

assigns the string `foo`.

```
var x = false && 'bar';
```

assigns the boolean `false`, since the first value is falsy and the second value doesn't get evaluated.

In your case, `'tags-button tag-colorless'`, is a string, and not-empty strings are always truthy, so it's like the first example above.

Maybe you meant concatanation, so substitute `&&` with `+`